# Formly doesn't update field after set properties in controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I need dynamically load options of a field. Before the options loaded, if user click the select dropdown, they will see a empty list. To prevent that, I want to disable the select when page load, and then enable it after the options load. 
The options loads fine, but the reset the disabled doesn't work

Code like

```
    {
    type: 'select', key: 'ref_code', defaultValue: '', templateOptions: {
        'required': false, 'label': 'Supporter',  
        'placeholder': 'loading...', 'options': [], 'disabled': true
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.to.loading = parentScope.ensure_option('resellers').then(function (items) {
            $scope.to.options = options.get('resellers');
            $scope.to.disabled = false;
            return $scope.to.options;
        });
    }
},
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You are loading it asynchronously but not waiting for the response to come back.

```
$scope.to.options = return options.get('resellers').then(function(response) {
     $scope.to.disabled = false;
     return response;
});
```